# Does within-group heterogeneity negatively impact random forest classification?

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, model-evaluation

I have two rather conceptual questions about random forest classifiers. Before we get there, I quickly want to lay out the problem I am working on: I have large a large data set consisting of 300 samples with about 370,000 data points each. There are 6 different groups of 50 samples each. I constructed a RF classifier with 1000 trees capable of prediting class labels in a second cohort of the same size & composition. It is known that there are certain subtypes within each group. PCA and other unsupervised methods reveal, however, that the major differences are indeed between the groups.

1. I wondered if within-group heterogeneity might influence classification results. From my understanding of how the trees are constructed, I assume it doesn't matter since samples from one group do not necessarily have to end up in the same terminal node.
2. I calculated the probability for a probe not to be chosen *at all in any of the trees* as p = 0.21 (for standard settings, i.e. square root of features for subsampling). Before I start increasing the number of trees, I would like to ask if there is something like a rule of thumb as to how many occurences of a variable are needed to reliably assess its importance. So basically, I am interested in the requirements to do feature selection.

All the best

Chris

Comment: Reading more about RF, I just realized my calculation in (2) is incorrect, as random features are not just selected once for a tree, but for _every_ splitpoint within a tree